# Can I run two virtual machines from one usb?

Tags: partitioning, usb, virtualbox

I have a usb drive with 32GB. I would like to setup a windows and a linux virtual machine. Can I partition the drive and install a vm for each on the same drive. I would not necessarily have to run both at the same time. (ie, sometimes windows, sometimes linux.)

Answer (score 3):

During the VM creation in a program like `VirtualBox`, when you are creating the `VXD` or `Virtual Drive` it asks you where you want to save it at.

You can save it anywhere you want to.  The USB is one place you can, but it will be recommended to have the USB drive in before you launch your VM application as it scans for all parts.  It will give an error if it can't find the VXD file(s).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to add to Terrance answer. You can have any number of vdi (virtualbox disk image) in your USB (limit it is the capacity of your usb). But one more thing to note, USB read will be slower than HDD, so it is recommended to keep the vdi file in your hard disk rather than USB.

Comment: @Chandrasekar I agree!  =)